# Can the Ricci curvature tensor vary while we hold fixed the Ricci scalar and the Weyl tensor? (Nordstrom Gravity)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I am reading about Nordstrom's second theory of gravity and have become confused. On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordstr%C3%B6m%27s_theory_of_gravitation) and [elsewhere](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/34568/spherically-symmetric-metric-in-nordstrom-gravity?show=34572#a34572) it is said that the theory is completely captured by its equations for the Ricci Scalar ($R=24\pi T$) and the vanishing of the Weyl tensor ($C_\text{abcd}=0$). But according to the [Ricci decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition) don't we also need to fix the (traceless) Ricci curvature? Can't $R_\text{ab}$ still vary while keeping $R$ and $C_\text{abcd}$ fixed? Doesn't this mean that the theory is incomplete since it underdetermines the metric?

Now I know that Einstein's equations also underdetermine the metric; $G_\text{ab}=T_\text{ab}$ leaves the Weyl tensor free to vary. These are gravitational waves. So you might think that in Nordstrom's theory the freedom to vary $R_\text{ab}$ captures its purely gravitational degrees of freedom. That is one perspective.

The way I am approaching things however is by starting from the flat formulation of the theory where there is just a field $\phi$ on a flat background $\eta_\text{ab}$. From here one does a conformal transformation of $\eta_\text{ab}\to g_\text{ab}=\phi^2\eta_\text{ab}$.  The metric that results is completely and uniquely fixed by this conformal transformation. So if the states in the flat theory are to be in one-to-one correspondence with states in the curved theory, then the equations in the latter theory must completely fix the metric.

Any help would be much appreciated.